# Сравнение строк Java

Tags: java, строки, сравнение

[image: Фот]

Вы видите, что:

```
h = "ah";
```

Но при сравнении `h` и `ah` выдаёт `false`.

Comment: В Java строки надо сравнивать через `equals`.

Comment: спасибо огромное!